# How to draw 1/4th circle in HTML5 using canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to draw circle,then make 4 parts equally of that circle and fill diffrent color in that diffrent part.

```
context.moveTo(500, 250);
context.lineTo(500, 50);
context.moveTo(500, 250);
context.arc(500,250,200,0,(Math.PI)+(Math.PI/2),false);![][1]`][1]
```

i have tried but not succesfully reached to my point.From above code pasted, i am just able to draw 1/4th circle.I want to draw complate circle and make equal 4 part of that circle.How it can be possible?

Comment: Then you should do so. And if you face a problem you can ask for a solution. But there is no error- or problem-description in your post. If you have a question – post it!

Answer (score 3):

**You have a good start.  Here are a few thoughts on your code:**

Drawing commands like `moveTo`, `lineTo` and `arc` must be started with `context.beginPath` or else all previous drawing commands will be redrawn during 'fill' and 'stroke'.  You can only fill with 1 color for each beginPath, so that's why it's important for you to do 4 sets of drawing commands beginning with beginPath so that you can fill with 4 different colors:

```
// begin a new set of drawing commands
// (or else all previous commands will be redrawn also)
context.beginPath();

context.moveTo(500, 250);
context.lineTo(500, 50);
context.moveTo(500, 250);
context.arc(500,250,200,0,(Math.PI)+(Math.PI/2),false);
```

BTW, You can simplify the drawing of your wedge using the fact that each part of a drawing command will automatically be connected with a line. This code will draw a full wedge using centerpoints [cx,cy], radius, and the starting & ending radian angles.

```
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(cx,cy);
context.arc(cx,cy,radius,startAngle,endAngle);
context.closePath();
context.fill();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/nyakoof2/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
context.moveTo(500, 50);
context.lineTo(500, 250);
context.arc(500,250,200,1.5*Math.PI,Math.PI,true);
context.lineTo(500,250);
context.stroke();
```

Comment: Using this code only 1/4 th part of circle can be draw.I want to draw complate circle and make equal 4 part of that circle.Then fill diffrant color in that differant part.How it can be possible?

Comment: Try to remove the `1.5*` part from `context.arc(500,250,200,1.5*Math.PI,Math.PI,true);` and draw a plus sign (+) with the same background color on top of the arc.

Answer (score 0):

is that you want : [`Working Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/m8a5y6ur/)

```
div#semi {
        width:300px;
        min-height: 300px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 300px 0 0 0px; /* depends on width */
        border-color: blue red red blue;
}
```